# Pushing a MFMailComposeViewController viewController

Tags: iphone

I am inside a tableViewController that has been pushed into view. This tableViewController has cells with accessoryButtons. When one of these buttons is tapped I would like to push a MFMailComposeViewController. Then I do this

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
// ... here controller is configured...
// then I would like to do

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

But as `MFMailComposeViewController` despite its incorrect name is a `NavigationController` itself, how can I push its `viewController` using `pushViewController`? I mean, what is the correct way to do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`presentModalViewController:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentModalViewController%3aanimated%3a) instead.

Comment: can I make it push the other viewController?